# ESLint with Webpack - How to include all project files?

Tags: webpack, eslint, webpack-2

I am working with a `webpack config` with `preloaders`.  This is what it is :

```
preLoaders: [
      ...
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        loader: 'eslint',
        include: [
          path.join(projectRoot, 'src')
        ],
        exclude: /node_modules/
      }
      ...
    ]
```

Now, this `configuration` will *es-lint* the code whenever the `entry file is affected`; however, it will not *lint* the code which is in the `project src folder`; but not yet connected with the `entry file`.

For ex. i'm writing code for `api section` which is not yet `import`ed in the `main.js` file.  In this case, the `es-lint` is not executed and this is the problem.

Is there a way to *es-lint* all files in the `src folder` instead of just the ones connected with the `main-entry file`

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is a way! If you are asking the webpack way. Then I am not sure. But you can Do mixing with eslint command line and come up with some npm script which fires

1) eslint in all project folder excluding node_modules, bundle.js use `.eslintignore`

2) Use webpack to transpile and bundling.

Comment: Thanks Ashutosh but I'm looking for the `webpack` way to take care of this.